# master file is not extending in sub folder in laravel

Tags: css, laravel, path, subdirectory, extends

I want to welcome.blade.php file css in email.blade.php file.

my email.blade.php file is in one sub folder.

when i extending

```
@extends('welcome')
```

it is showing me these errors in console

```
reset:20     GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/password/css/styles.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
reset:21     GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/password/css/style2.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
reset:22     GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/password/css/image_slider.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
reset:23     GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/password/css/validation.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
reset:99     GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/password/js/scripts.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
sb-forms-latest.js:5 Uncaught Error: GET_ELEMENTS: page-top -> form[data-sb-form-api-token]
```

this is my email.blade.php file path

/var/www/html/useradmintest_13_july_eve/useradmintest/resources/views/auth/passwords/email.blade.php

and this is my welcome.blade.php file path

/var/www/html/useradmintest_13_july_eve/useradmintest/resources/views/welcome.blade.php

Comment: How do you load your assets in your blade file? Probably a missing leading slash to start from the server's top directory

Comment: yes when i add `<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />` ../ in this path then css is coming , but i can't add that as my other blade files in not passwords folder.

Comment: Use `href="/css/styles.css"`, add a leading slash

Comment: it's worked , can you explain?

Comment: See my first comment, a leading slash starts from the server's topmost/"root" folder, so it'll also work when called from files in subfolder(s)

Comment: you can do it like: `{{ asset('/css/style.css') }}`, `{{ }}` prevents XSS attacks and use asset helper from laravel.